# Best way to include table (of data) in a question

Tags: support, markdown, tables

I would like to ask a question on Stack Overflow which includes a table of data from a MySQL database. What is the best way to include a table of data in a question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some people like ASCII Art. Though it's annoying to type in:

```
| Username  | Password  | Email_Addr |
--------------------------------------
| Username1 | Password1 | Email 1    |
| Username2 | Password2 | Email 2    |
| Username3 | Password3 | Email 3    |
| Username4 | Password4 | Email 4    |
| Username5 | Password5 | Email 5    |
```

Comment: thanks - that's perfect (I guess i was wondering if there was a built-in table function but that works great)

Comment: Just remember to surround the table in <pre> tags.

Comment: see http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Answer (score 6):

As someone that answers a lot of SQL questions the best way In my opinion to include a table of data is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
Username varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
Password varchar(30),
Email_Addr varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO foo
SELECT 'Username1','Password1','Email 1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Username2','Password2','Email 2' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Username3','Password3','Email 3' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Username4','Password4','Email 4' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Username5','Password5','Email 5'
```

It gets tedious very quickly adding quotes onto strings, inserting commas and removing vertical bars, underscores and other such artefacts in order to set up a test table to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to create ASCII art you could upload an image.  Simply create the table yourself (spreadsheets work well for this) and then upload a screenshot of the table.

[image: # Sample Table Image #]

Another route would be to create a table in a [google spreadsheet](https://spreadsheets.google.com/) and then use the publish as a web page option to create a link to it.

Comment: No. This is not a good idea. It just increases the amount of typing that potential answerers have to do.

Comment: While I also appreciate DDL/DML to setup SQL questions and am glad you included that as an answer (+1), sometimes a visual representation would be useful.  In particular, users new to SQL may not know how to generate table creation/population SQL.  I'd certainly prefer picture of their table over the vague two sentence descriptions I often see.

Comment: An image also works for any tabular data whether it is database related or not.

Comment: Yes true it's definitely better than a vague sentence! My -1 is locked in now so I can't remove it. Shame the support in the markdown editor is so non existent for tables [as discussed in this related feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/easier-way-to-represent-db-tables-when-asking-db-questions)

Comment: @Martin, I edited the question.  I'm not sure, but I think that means you can up-vote it back to zero.