# display tabular data

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, data-dump, tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easier way to represent DB tables when asking DB questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/easier-way-to-represent-db-tables-when-asking-db-questions)

How do I represent formatted tabular data in Stackoverflow ?

Basically I need to show content of a table; options that I have found are

- use `code` blocks

and format it

```
pushd                   if
E:\bin\bat\test1.bat    c:\bin\bat\abc.bat
E:\bin\bat\test2.bat    c:\bin\bat\xyz.bat
E:\bin\bat\test3.bat
```

- capture screenshot and embed as done in [LIsting all the text files in a folder and writing information to excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585815/listing-all-the-text-files-in-a-folder-and-writing-information-to-excel-sheet/6586817#6586817)

Comment: You can also use `<pre></pre>` blocks in your posts -- no pesky syntax-hilighting with them. ... ... Make this a feature-request.  There's been a few times when the `<table>` tag would have been handy.

Comment: See, also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/148310

Comment: Here's the official solution (for now): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/easier-way-to-represent-db-tables-when-asking-db-questions/96483#96483

Answer (score 0):

Why not just block quotes? as in (<**blockquote**>)

> How about this?

Comment: 1. its not fixed width 2.cant extend for multilines

Comment: what do you mean by "fixed width" and "multilines?"

Comment: fixed width =http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font multilines=a<enter>b