# How to format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow post?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I want to format an SQL table the right way in a Stack Overflow question.

**ID** **Name**

1 Tom

I know the example above is not the right way. I even tried an HTML table approach, but it's still wrong. Please help, because I need to include SQL tables later...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but at least spelling the name of the site right and not using txtspeak would be much better ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [best way to include table (of data) in a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38115/best-way-to-include-table-of-data-in-a-question) or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5255/please-add-support-for-tables-in-answers-and-questions

Comment: it might be a duplicate but strange, the votes on this question is much higher..

Answer (score 63, accepted):

See

[Is there a web app to create ASCII art tables?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6700/is-there-a-webapp-to-create-ascii-art-tables)

From our very own [Senseful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/143909/senseful)!

I just copied and pasted this from SQL Server Management studio:

```
-1  Community   210
1   Jeff Atwood 5636
2   Geoff Dalgas    148
3   Jarrod Dixon    101
4   Joel Spolsky    959
```

Into [Senseful's web app](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) and got

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ -1 ║  Community   ║ 210  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ Jeff Atwood  ║ 5636 ║
║  2 ║ Geoff Dalgas ║  148 ║
║  3 ║ Jarrod Dixon ║  101 ║
║  4 ║ Joel Spolsky ║  959 ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

(I probably should have ticked the "no header" option...)

Comment: This is still broken for me in FF5.

Comment: @jon still can't repro, see screenshot with Firefox 5 about shown at http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/765/ff5asciitable.png

Comment: :( http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/files/370/1c3fafd9a8ea4cd1a4ef10e2123841e8/fixed-width-still-borked-png

Comment: @jon there's something busted in your OS or config somewhere? What OS? I am using Windows 7. I noticed your windows are not themed as if they are on Windows 7..

Comment: Win7 x64. I think I have font smoothing or something turned *off* -- I will play with my settings later today and let you know.

Comment: Enabling ClearType fixed the problem. (I'm turning it back off, though.)

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Glad you found the utility useful! This is exactly the reason I developed it, so thanks for the link!

Comment: @JonSeigel: does using the "MySQL" instead of "Unicode Art" style still make it appear broken for you?

Comment: This stopped working, was an excellent tool (July, 2016)

Comment: This is working here: https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/ @Dave

Comment: If you have a lot of data, you can format it using that app in the link above to create an HTML snippet. Then you can embed it into the stackoverflow post as a code-snippet, and the result is quite gorgeous.

Comment: 13 October 2017 new URL: https://senseful.github.io/text-table/

Comment: This is stale. There is good table support now: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support