# Creating beautiful tables

Tags: discussion, markdown, code-formatting, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables)
>   [How to format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-to-format-sql-tables-in-a-stack-overflow-post)

I was wondering how users are able to create *beatiful tables* of how their sql tables look like. See one below:

[image: Beautiful]

It is so neat and pretty.

Comment: Is that from an SO question? If so, just click edit and see the formatting used... ;P

Comment: Geez why didn't I think of that? Sigh. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's all just judicious use of spaces.

There's [a nice tool to help format ASCII tables at sensefulsolutions.com](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html).

Comment: Now that's what I'm talking about! thanks.

Comment: But, @Jack, please [take mobile users into account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables/73567#73567). (And maybe even screen readers, but I guess that's hopeless with any ASCII-like output.)