# Repository of useful pro-forma comments

Tags: support, comments, pro-forma-comments

Every tag has its questions that make the same mistake(s) over and over and over again. (But some tags more than others.)

That's where Benjol's [pro forma comments script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) comes in. The only downside to this great script is that it uses local storage, so if you switch browsers or machine, you lose your data! The team [doesn't seem to be interested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117963) in incorporating it into the core (at least not at the moment) so  this question may serve to collect good snippets here in lieu of a real central repository.

To use, click "edit", and fetch the snippet's markdown source code.

> **Note**: For these snippets to be easy to copy&paste, do not use the editor's linking method, but inline links, like so:
>
> ```
> [This is a link](http://www.this.is.the.url)
> ```

[Magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) might help too:

> ```
> See [so].
> ```

Comment: Are these for SO only? I've been meaning to drum some up for UX. I could just post them on our meta instead

Comment: @Ben it might make sense to post a separate one on Meta.UX. If this gets properly used one day, it might become pretty crowded... feel free to copy whatever you deem useful of course!

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but why don't you just create a remote source?  The folks on Ask Ubuntu did: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3007/pro-forma-comments-now-support-remote-sources-should-we-set-this-up

Comment: [SOPython](https://sopython.com/wiki/Useful_Comments) has a collection in their wiki which contains some comments which are not here (I was looking for "please don't vandalize").

Comment: Isn't this a [List of X (that is, a poll)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57248/364344)? Does "this is not a discussion or poll site" not appy to the meta sites?

Comment: @NH it doesn't apply *exactly* as on the main sites, no. Much more license here.

Comment: Related *[Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000)* (covers magic links in both questions/answers, comments, and chat).

Answer (score 76):

## Context: General Questions

### Website is "broken", no code in question, just link to site

`Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!`

Preview:

> Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just
> link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will
> lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For
> more info, see  [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just
> paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/)
> Thanks!

### Needs to demonstrate research

`Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]`

Preview:

> Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and
> why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the
> time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious
> answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant
> answer! See also: [How To
> Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

### Write my Code for Me

`Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.`

Preview:

> Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

### Insufficient Code Example

`Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).`

Preview:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

### Do my homework

`We will not do your entire homework for you, only help you with it. Show us your code and focus on a specific problem you're having. Tell us what you already understood, where you are struggling, and [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).`

Preview:

> We will not do your entire homework for you, only help you with it. Show us your code and focus on a specific problem you're having. Tell us what you already understood, where you are struggling, and [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

### Non-English Question

`Stack Overflow is an English-only site, and all the questions and answers **must** be in English. See [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange), [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content), and [ask]`

Preview:

> Stack Overflow is an English-only site, and all the questions and
> answers **must** be in English. See [Do posts have to be in English on
> Stack
> Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange),
> [How do I deal with non-English
> content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content),
> and [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

### Unspecific / Add more Information

`Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far, with a code example? / What do you expect? / What error do you get? For help, take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".`

Preview:

> Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far, with a code example? / What do you expect? / What error do you get? For help, take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

---

## Context: General Comments

### Self-answers in a comment

`You should consider posting this as an answer and accepting it so others can see that your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself :)`

Preview:

> You should consider posting this as an answer and accepting it so others can see that your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself :)

---

## Context: Answers

### Asking why this is not working on an Answer

`This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)`

Preview:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

### Posting a link without any explanation as an answer

`While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.`

Preview:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

### Duplicate/unnecessary late answer

`Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers. Your answer is (included in)/(very similar to) [this answer](link/to/answer), and not very useful since it does not add any new value or information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers. Either edit your answer to add value or delete it altogether; this will ensure all questions and answers on the site remain useful and not scattered/duplicated.`

Preview:

> Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers. Your answer is (included in)/(very similar to) this answer, and not very useful since it does not add any new value or information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers. Either edit your answer to add value or delete it altogether; this will ensure all questions and answers on the site remain useful and not scattered/duplicated.

Comment: I'm not *too* sure about ending your comments with *thanks*. That risks annoying any sensitive person who's had their 'thanks' edited out of a question.

Comment: Marking helpful answers as accepted: Removed as the system nags people to accept answers already, this is just *noise* and no one cleans up the comments once answers *are* accepted.

Comment: Removed the image hosting and the formatting problems: these are edits that other users can and should make.  It's a huge reason why we have collaborative editing.  People typically do not go back to see if the editing was actually done after leaving the comment.  If it was done, then the comment is obsolete and just noise.

Comment: `You should edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that those answering this question have something work with. Also let us know what you've tried, what went wrong and anything else you can think of that would help us help you.` I use that one (or incarnations of it) all the time.

Comment: On SO, [you can now use `[mcve]` in comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299455/1835379), which results in `[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)`

Comment: There is a homework-specific question on stackoverflow meta, so:`We will not do your entire homework for you, only help you with it. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). Show us your code and focus on a specific problem you're having. Tell us what you already understood, where you are struggling, and [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).`

Answer (score 22):

## Context: SQL Questions

### The question fails to specify the RDBMS and the answer will be sensitive to this

```
Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the
appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers
that take advantage of language or product features that are not
universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your
question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.
```

Preview:

> Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the
>   appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers
>   that take advantage of language or product features that are not
>   universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your
>   question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

### The question needs some sample data and desired output

```
Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.) Additional schema
information and where your attempts failed would also help us to help you better.
```

Preview:

> Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
>   format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
>   post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.) Additional schema
>   information and where your attempts failed would also help us to help you better.

### Avoid using deprecated mysql_* functions in PHP

```
There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are 
[**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** 
and were [**removed in PHP 7**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning). You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or 
[MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.
```

Preview:

> There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are 
>   [**officially
>   deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer
>   maintained**  and were [**removed in PHP
>   7**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning). You
>   should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or 
>   [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your
>   project in the future.

Comment: Aside from not being related to PHP, I don't think adding some meme is helpful, @Truth. (Also, it won't render that nicely [on all machines](http://superuser.com/questions/232636/displaying-unicode-on-chrome-vs-firefox).)

Comment: Here are the reasons for me removing each of the sections that I did and what you *should* be doing instead in these situations (instead of just generating noise):

Comment: Answer cites W3Schools as a reference: W3Schools is by no means the only wrong place on the internet.  Also, some of the pages are actually *right*.  Edit the reference to a better reference.

Comment: Lack of error checking: Using MySQLi: Vote/flag as too localized if that *is* the error.  Also says RTFM.

Comment: Lack of error checking: Using `mysql_*`: Vote/flag as too localized if that *is* the error.  Also says RTFM.

Comment: Using older MySQL library: User might not have any choice, this is just preaching.  Doesn't help with the question *as asked*.  If they *do* switch, then vote/flag as too localized.

Comment: SQL injection Vulnerability: SQL Injection is by no means the only security flaw that people have in their code.  This is preachy.  Edit the code to actually *use* the methods that sanitize input instead.

Comment: HTML & Regex: Removed as the poster might not be able to use the html library.  Why not ask why they don't use an HTML parsing library, or better yet, put it up as an answer.

Comment: @casperOne: I have to disagree with most of your removals. If people ask a question which exhibits these problems, but the question is actually about something else, are we supposed to just ignore them and wait for the question "I just got hacked... why?". In this scenario, leaving a comment like the ones you've just removed (IMHO) is the right thing to do; it's not an answer as it doesn't answer the question. It's not VtC close-worthy (as you said we should do); it's just a prod in the right direction *which is right*.

Comment: @Matt Ask *specific, tailored* questions *about* the question in the comments.  Don't just dump a bunch of pre-formatted stuff and then just leave.  This is the *core* of the problem.  As refined as you want to make any of these comments, you're really just telling the user "go somewhere else" and you aren't really trying to help them with *that* problem.  There is no "one comment to rule them all" (even in specific contexts).  When you try to get one for a particular context, it's nothing more than preaching and doesn't help anyone, while reducing the signal-to-noise ratio.

Comment: @casperOne It probably would have been easier just to delete this answer and restore mine :P

Answer (score 14):

## Context: General Questions

### Insufficient Information

```
It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be
reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context,
and/or post code samples of what you have done
```

Preview:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post code samples of what you have done

### Low-Quality Posts by New User

```
Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.
```

Preview:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about), and "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" before asking a question.

Answer (score 12):

## Context: MSO Questions

### Belongs on Stack Overflow

```
This question is [off topic here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), but
might be suitable for the [main site](https://stackoverflow.com/). Before
re-posting there, please first [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) 
to see if it has been asked before. Be sure to read [How to ask]
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) first!
```

Preview:

> This question is [off topic here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), but might be suitable for the [main site](https://stackoverflow.com/). Before re-posting there, please first [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) to see if it has been asked before. Be sure to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) first!

## Context: MSO Comments

### Downvotes on Meta are different

```
Please note that [downvotes on Meta may appear to be different]
(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). Here, downvotes 
may indicate disagreement in addition to any criticism of the post itself. 
Verbose criticisms will be expanded upon in answers and comments. 
Hope that clears things up!
```

Preview:

> Please note that [downvotes on Meta may appear to be different](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). Here, downvotes may indicate disagreement in addition to any criticism of the post itself. Verbose criticisms will be expanded upon in answers and comments. Hope that clears things up!

Comment: Appear to be different? They *are*.

Comment: Can't MSO questions just be migrated to SO? Why bother with a comment which encourages re-posting, when you can just vote to migrate instead?

Comment: @Ajedi32 If someone posts a programming question on MSO, that means (a) they have no clue about how Stack Exchange works; (b) specifically, they don't know what makes a good SO question; (c) they haven't searched SO to see if there's already an answer. They should fix all of that before asking at SO.

Comment: @Fundamental Never mind. I was under the impression that MSO posts could be migrated to SO by the community. I just checked and it doesn't appear that that's the case.

My point *was* going to be that you shouldn't recommend reposting on SO at all, since the original question is going to be migrated and reposting would just result in a duplicate. Given that questions can't be migrated from MSO to SO (without a mod?) though, I actually agree with the wording of that comment.

Answer (score 10):

## Context: New User Education and Recruitment

These snippets are for gently guiding new users toward being fully-participating members of the community. They might be most useful in smaller communities, where community members are interested in actively recruiting and educating new users.

### Unregistered

```
Please consider [registering](/users/login) your account, which will
[give you access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account)
to more of the site's features.
```

Preview:

> Please consider [registering](/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

### Default username

```
I suggest that you [edit your profile](/users/edit/current) and give yourself a
name!
```

Preview:

> I suggest that you [edit your profile](/users/edit/current) and give yourself a name!

### Answer looks like a discussion post

```
We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a
Q&A site, where we reserve the answer space for answers. Please check out our
short [tour]. Could you please [edit] this to more directly address the 
question?
```

Preview:

> We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site, where we reserve the answer space for answers. Please check out our short [tour](/tour). Could you please [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/136609/edit) this to more directly address the question?

### Suggest further exploration

```
I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest, perhaps starting with
our ### other [tag:SELECTATAG] questions.
```

Preview:

> I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest, perhaps starting with our 2700 other [comments](/questions/tagged/comments) questions.

Comment: Adapted from http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/190/welcoming-new-users

Answer (score 8):

## Context: JavaScript Answers

### Don't just fiddle

```
Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem in your post and **don't just 
include a link to jsFiddle**. Links rot, and your post should stand alone from any other resource; 
 this question will lose any value to future visitors if jsFiddle is blocked or goes away in the future!
```

Preview:

> Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE) that demonstrates your problem in your post and **don't just include a link to jsFiddle**. Links rot, and your post should stand alone from any other resource; this question will lose any value to future visitors if jsFiddle is blocked or goes away in the future!

### ES5 Notice

```
The above snippet uses code from the [ECMAScript 5 specification](http://es5.github.com/), 
which is [not supported in older browsers](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/).
If you wish to support them, you need to either alter the snippet yourself or 
make use of an [ES5 shim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732846/how-to-provide-es5-shim)
or [polyfiller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221757/polyfill-or-workarounds-for-ecmascript5-new-features).
```

Preview:

> The above snippet uses code from the [ECMAScript 5 specification](http://es5.github.com/), which is [not supported in older browsers](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/). If you wish to support them, you need to either alter the snippet yourself or make use of an [ES5 shim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732846/how-to-provide-es5-shim) or [polyfiller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221757/polyfill-or-workarounds-for-ecmascript5-new-features).

### Answer cites W3Schools as a reference

```
W3Schools often contains out of date and incorrect information.
For JavaScript, please reference the 
[Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/) 
- it is far more likely to remain accurate and updated over time.
```

Preview:

> W3Schools often contains out of date and incorrect information. For JavaScript, please reference the [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/) - it is far more likely to remain accurate and updated over time.

Comment: "consider what'd happen if jsFiddle **went** down in the future." Is that correct? "went" has to be replaced with "goes", not?

Comment: @Rob W: "were to go down", I believe.

Comment: The w3schools general comment is useless, what's important is if the actual page referenced is incorrect, which a pro-forma comments script cannot address.  It's just noise and will be deleted on sight.

Comment: ES5 Notice: Removed because there are people in corporate environments that *are* locked into older browsers.

Comment: @casperOne: that doesn't prevent web pages including poly fillers to bridge the gap between older browsers and ES5, which is what the comment stipulates. Furthermore, I don't think this is anyone's call to remove potentially useful comments from this post. If you don't find them useful, don't add them to your pro-forma list.

Comment: @Matt: the intent here is refinement and discussion of these comments - which you're doing. CW allows just about anyone to make changes, or revert changes - which you've done. As long as folks don't get into edit wars, we're fine.

Comment: @casperOne: I was polite enough to explain why I rolled back your edit, and why I think the redactions you made were wrong. I would ask you to do the same, as this is a community made and maintained resource, not yours.

Comment: @Matt 1) I'm a member of the community, let's not forget. 2) I've edited anything bordering on preachy or not *directly* answering the question at hand.  Comments are meant first and foremost to elaborate on the question *not* to evangelize.  It's not for "oh, you might be interested in..." or "you're doing this wrong, go read this somewhere else to see why".  That's what *answers* are for.  That said, I'm rolling it back for these reasons, as we will not tolerate evangelism or a RTFM/GTFO (which these are a polite form of) comments on the site.

Comment: @Matt: You can keep your version if you like, I'll merely downvote it.  The w3schools hate is misguided; it's mostly due to w3schools SEO success, not some grave, catastrophic hazard, and your comment simply isn't true on any meaningful level.  I've seen textbooks that are worse than w3schools.

Comment: I detest w3schools links, but tend to agree that the fear-mongering in that comment wasn't productive. I've revised it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: FWIW, the w3schools link wasn't mine, someone else added it. My comments were more about the approach of wading in and editing a community resource, and then rolling back a rollback without any intention of explaining the rationale and providing justification.

Comment: @casperOne: I'm not saying you aren't a member of the community. If this was *your* post with no CW, I'd respect your decision to rollback an edit, and not be too incensed if you provided no justification for it; however, as things are, you waded in here and edited a community resource (some of which is my work, yes), and provided no rationale or justification of your actions; even when I clearly disagreed with them (otherwise I wouldn't have rolled back).

Comment: None of these comments (IMO) evangelize the post, and there is perfectly legitimate reasons to use these comments, where a comment is not appropriate; as I pointed out in [my other comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments#comment503677_136610)

Comment: @Matt But it's CW, so you made it fair game for edits.  And I *did* post reasons why, after you asked, I don't see the point of bringing them up again after that was done.  Your initial statement of "as this is a community made and maintained resource" implied I was somehow not a part of that, because I was maintaining it (if I misconstrued that, then apologies).  As for your evangelism, it doesn't have to be *for* something, it can be *against* something, which is the type of evangelism that the w3schools falls into.

Comment: @Matt The ES5 comment isn't as bad, but it's just kind of preachy and like most of the other "use this technology instead" comments, doesn't take the time to actually *ask* the user *why* they're using it.  If they simply don't know, *then* take the time to educate them, but if they do know, and have to use these technologies for some reason (again, these reasons are irrelevant to the question at hand), then a drive by comments of this nature do nothing but create noise.

Comment: @casperOne: I don't dispute CW permits changes, but I think I would have expected changes as *radical* as you performed (e.g. removing half of the pro-forma comments collectively) to have been discussed first. I didn't mean to distance you from the community in my comment, so I apologize if it was interpreted as such.

Comment: @casperOne: Regardless, I  think we both have very different mentalities here; I can see every comment you removed having *some* use-case on Stack Overflow, however, I'm expecting the user to determine the correct use for them appropriately. You however, seem to be removing the comments unless they can be used in *every* circumstance. At the moment it's just our 2 opinions; should more community members get involved and lean towards a particular POV, I'd of course be happy to go with the majority verdict.

Comment: @casperOne *ES5 Notice: Removed because there are people in corporate environments that are locked into older browsers.* - isn't that the *point* of the notice? It's a comment for the benefit of precisely the people you describe, warning them the code they're reading won't work in all environments - and it is left as task for the reader to decide whether they care. I can't make sense of your reasoning for deleting that entry in any way besides supposing that you misread it.

Answer (score 7):

## Context: Facebook.SO

### Facebook account problems

```
Sorry, [so] is not Facebook's customer support.  
We deal with **questions regarding programming** on the Facebook platform. 
For regular Facebook support, please see 
[Facebook's Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help).
```

Preview:

> Sorry, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is not Facebook's customer support. We deal with **questions regarding programming** on the Facebook platform. For regular Facebook support, please see [Facebook's Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help).

#### Reporting Facebook bugs

```
Sorry, [so] is not the place to report bugs on Facebook. 
Stack Overflow is a **Q&A site for professional programmers**. To 
report bugs on Facebook please visit the [Facebook Bug System]
(https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/).
```

Preview:

> Sorry, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is not the place to report bugs on Facebook. Stack Overflow is a **Q&A site for professional programmers**. To report bugs on Facebook, please visit the [Facebook Bug System](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/).

### Facebook feature requests

```
Sorry, [so] is not Facebook's customer support.  
Stack Overflow is a **programmers Q&A site**.  
If you would like to suggest a new feature to Facebook, you can do so at 
their [Suggestion & Feedback Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/suggestions/).
```

Preview:

> Sorry, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is not Facebook's customer support. Stack Overflow is a **programmers Q&A site**. If you would like to suggest a new feature to Facebook, you can do so at their [Suggestion & Feedback Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/suggestions/).

Comment: "Stack Overflow is a Q&A site for professional programmers" - The help center *also* mentions hobbyist programmers.

Answer (score 2):

**Context: Send Notification**

When more than one user commented on the OP's question, but the commenter didn’t tag a username when writing a comment, in that case, commented users don't get a notification.

```
If you want to notify the user, please [@tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/307988) their name in the comment.
```

Preview:

> If you want to notify the user, please [@tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/307988) their name in the comment.

Comment: At least point to a comment FAQ.

Comment: Better would be something like (with correct FAQ link)... `If you want to notify the user, please [@tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/307988) their name in the comment.`

Answer (score 1):

## Context: C++ questions

### Access violation

```
Weird behavior often comes from undefined behavior caused by wrong memory manipulation. If you're experiencing **access violation** (segmentation fault), please try tools like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or [AddressSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) to determine the root of the problem.
```

Preview:

> Weird behavior often comes from undefined behavior caused by wrong memory manipulation. If you're experiencing **access violation** (segmentation fault), please try tools like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or [AddressSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) to determine the root of the problem.

Answer (score -8):

## Highly upvoted but outdated answer

```
Don't forget to downvote this answer if you find it **unhelpful** or **outdated**.
```

> Don't forget to downvote this answer if you find it **unhelpful** or **outdated**.

See more: [How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/260800)

Comment: So ironically...

Comment: Isn't it inappropriate to talk about votes in comments?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q why?