# Voting to close with pre-defined list of helpful advice

Tags: feature-request, comments, vote-to-close

This feature request is primarily targeted at users with "cast close and reopen votes" privileges (3k rep).

**Proposal:**

Currently, new users may post a question that is either off-topic, unclear, or not-constructive. An example would be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238857/suggestions-to-learn-css-html-and-php

Instead of just voting to close, I usually would take the time to point out (via comment) to the user on what to do next, like read the about section of the site, or how to ask a proper question in the future.

It would be helpful if after voting to close, a list of helpful comments appears that we can select from and automatically post to notify the user.

**Example list of helpful comments:**

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post code samples of what you have done (i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))
>
> Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about), and "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" before asking a question.
>
> ... *(other helpful advice is shown, **depending on the reason selected** for the close vote)*

**Possible Benefits:**

- The pre-defined comments available can be managed by SO/moderators
- New users will get useful advice on what to do next, rather than just see all the negative votes and *leave the site*, or post *another* low-quality question
- Time-saver for editors/moderators, considering SO see many new users and such low-quality posts everyday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No new feature is required for this. You can use the [pro-forma comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) user script.

Some communities even coordinate what pro-forma comments they think should *commonly* be used. For example, [on Ask Ubuntu Meta we have this question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1323/what-prewritten-pro-forma-userscript-comments-can-we-use-and-share). Stack Overflow has [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments), but considering how many more people use SO than AU, it doesn't seem to have caught on as much.

Using pro-forma comments for this lets people who are most interested in doing this do it, while not burdening people with an additional click-through dialog where they may be tempted to click something that's not really helpful.

If you're already using pro-forma comments, great. If you think more people should use them, you can tell people about them. If you haven't used them, check it out!