# Flag for unclear question

Tags: discussion, flags

My question is about flags...
Many times the users asks question with no code, without effort and their work behind his question. We have to ask/comment him "**Show your effort**" , "**What are doing so far** " and so on.. So Is there any kind of flag for this ? or If it is not *It should be added*.

Comment: Since [Shog's post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort) I got a kind of restrained/unsettle with flagging  these questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are already flags available to mark the question as closed...

If the question shows lack of effort.. Most of the cases, following flags can be used

> [image]

If the question is very unclear and clarification is essential for solving then following flag can be used

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several flags available under *it should be closed for another reason...* (at least in SO)

- off-topic because...

  > This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the
  >   community. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites,
  >   please describe it in detail. See also: What is "meta"? How does it
  >   work?
- off-topic because...

  > The problem described here can no longer be reproduced. Changes to
  >   the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered
  >   it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new
  >   question.
- unclear what you're asking