# Why is this question offtopic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, off-topic

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071258/how-to-iterate-over-all-files-in-a-given-pattern

I've found similiar questions, such as: [How to list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python?rq=1)
Which got upvoted.

How is it unclear what I'm asking, especially when there's an accepted answer?

Edit:

I've taken some time reading on how to write good questions and stumbled upon this discussion: (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow)

> **A note on Effort**
>
> There were a handful of people who interpreted "minimal understanding" as a euphemism for "visible effort" or even "a wall of code". That was never the intent, as it's never been something I've observed as a widespread implicit requirement on Stack Overflow: a clearly-written, reasonably-scoped, answerable programming question should strive to include as much information as necessary and no more; doing otherwise is a much more frequent source of frustration. You can find extensive discussion on this topic here: [Should Stack Overflow be awarding "A"s for Effort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort)?

One more relevant quote:

> I'm sorry, but... When I'm trying to solve a problem and searching for
>   similar questions  on Stack Overflow, I really don't care how much
>   effort the asker demonstrates in his  question. In fact, unless that
>   effort translated directly into a clear, concise question  that I can
>   easily identify as being close to my own and then quickly scroll past
>   to get to  the answers, I'm rather resentful of ostentatious displays
>   of effort.

The point being, this is a Q&A site, questions of the sort "How do I
solve X" should be welcomed as long as they are clear and relevant
(and unique).

Comment: Did you read the comments against the question? namely the first comment: *" You must show some effort. What you have researched, what code you have tried, why it didn't work? –  Christian Jan 12 at 4:21 "*.

Comment: @JonW What does that have to do with "Unclear what you're asking" and what does that have to do with the question I linked to? Shouldn't I take example of high voted questions when coming to ask one?

Comment: Well I refer you to the 3rd comment on your post: "*asked Jul 8 '10 StackOverflow had changed a lot since that date. –  Christian Jan 12*" I think you should read all those comments against your post and follow the advice given there.

Comment: @JonW see edit.

Comment: P.s. it's not exactly unique: [How to find all files in current directory with filenames that match a pattern in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417745/how-to-find-all-files-in-current-directory-with-filenames-that-match-a-certain-p), [Python search file using wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348753/python-search-file-using-wildcard), [Python get a list of filtered files in directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225564/python-get-a-filtered-list-of-files-in-directory). So if it's reopened, it's probably a dupe.

Comment: @Bart So suddenly the question became clear to you?

Comment: The answer you've accepted clarifies your question. Which shouldn't be necessary, but it did.

Comment: +1 because clearly, the OP doesn't understand how rule changes work, and neither did I at first. Honestly. When you first came here, did you want to learn after using SO for a while? Yes, otherwise you wouldn't be here now! When voting, take into account that this user hasn't been using the site as much as we have.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for taking the time to find the recent, relevant discussions here on meta; it's gratifying to see folks willing to go out of their way to investigate the reasoning behind things that happen on the site. Unfortunately, you missed [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), linked to from the Unclear close reason itself, which starts with:

> #### Search, and research
>
> ...and keep track of what you find. Even if you don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, including links to related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest.

I guess it didn't help that the comments on the question ignored it too. You'll find that it's often worth taking comments here with a big grain of salt; folks like to throw them out without really putting much thought into them. Aaanyway...

**The problem with your question is that there are several hundred existing questions on the topic of finding files matching various patterns using Python.** Maybe not the *exact* same pattern you were looking to match, but reasonably close. Indeed, I've gone ahead and closed your question as a duplicate, since I suspect if you'd run across the question I found with a few seconds worth of searching, you wouldn't have needed to ask your own.

Here's the kicker: if you *had* gone through a few of the existing questions and found them lacking, you could've had the decency to drop a link to one of them into *your* question, along with a short explanation for how you found it lacking. A title that reflected this sort of problem wouldn't go amiss either. Is this strictly required? No... But it *shows respect* for the other folks using the site. And when you show others respect, they're much more likely to return the favor.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misinterpreting it, but your statement on comments (and their validity) seems a bit too dismissive to me, bordering on the "often safe to ignore". Surely that's not your intent?

Comment: No, not ignore - but don't assume they're telling the whole story either.

Answer (score 5):

> How is it unclear what I'm asking, especially when there's an accepted answer.

The fact that you accepted an answer doesn't make it a valid question.

It was close because it does not show any proof of effort on your part. You simply put it like this.

```
I have this, please give my that.
```

The closing reason points to [this page about how to ask good questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  I recommend you read it as it will help you understand what kind of questions are accepted on the site.

Comment: There are literally hundred of thousands of questions in SO which has the form "How do I solve X". Sometimes you have a problem which you don't know how to approach.

Comment: @Shmoopy The question you are referring to in your post is more than 3 years old. Rules were different back then. It doesn't mean this question should be closed though. It means that from now on, rules should be followed when posting here. I'm not the one making the rules here.

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: Except that [shog's post on closing changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow) and similar posts the last few weeks have consistently said effort is not a reason to close a question.  Downvote or ignore it instead.

Comment: @Troyen Yeah yet another way shog9 found to bring the quality on the site down without listening to reasoning from the community. Good for him