# Should I post my try if it is useless?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I have this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774887/regex-validate-a-mathematical-expression), when I asked it it was closed by the reason of :

> Questions asking for code must *demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved*. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the "expected" results.

Even though I included my attempted solution and why it didn't work. But the problem is that I didn't include a code, because it was obsolete: it would only provide additional characters to the text.

The question has a perfect answer and it was accepted. I don't really get the problem.(I didn't mind it being closed but till now I'm still getting downvotes which I don't like.)

Comment: That close reason does not exist any more... See [should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/)

Comment: I don't see any attempted solution in your question.

Comment: That's a heavily debated subject due to the fact that specific close reason was removed a few weeks ago because it was being wrongly used.  I can say the most likely reason your question was closed was because you didn't even make an attempt to write your own regex pattern, or if you did, you didn't show it.  So if you tried something, you should post it.  It's never useless as you can learn what you did wrong in your attempt.

Comment: @psubsee2003 the peoblem isn't a wrong regex pattern it is regex itself, I learned that I can't use regex in such cases, so posting my regex would be a really bad idea even if it was correct.

Comment: I think that a lot of people like to see the code that you've tried because it helps provide context as to what you are trying to accomplish. We also don't want to feel like we are a code writing service, doing your job/school assignment for you. There are questions, though, where offering up code that clearly doesn't come close to achieving the desired solution, would only detract from the quality of the question.

Comment: @crush: I think you need to make it the answer (comment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should post what you've tried so far.  It is a good way to show details you might not have included in your questions, such as contextual clues (as @crush noted in the comments).

It's also good for us to see what abilities you have; a suggestion should be something you can reasonably understand and use, not something that you could paste in but not understand.  If there are multiple ways to solve the problem, as there almost always are, it guides us to the correct choice for you.