# In which case are "give me the code" questions ok?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, question-quality

The title says it all : when is a "give me the code" question ok?

---

I did follow those suggestions when asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21553669/476681), and the answer is not that trivial. I got one not very serious answer.

Comment: It isn't. But I'm feeling there is a "then why is this okay?" behind this question.

Comment: In no situations. Unless the poster has put "URGENT!!" in the title of the question. The more exclamation marks that are added the faster it will get answers.

Comment: It might be OK when the one requesting the code also show efforts and/or research. Just "give me teh codez is **never** OK.

Comment: If it's a regex question since it's impossible to learn to write regex by yourself. :P

Comment: I was about to post this question!

Comment: I agree with all above, but I swear Shog9 said that as long as the question can be answered in a few lines (e.g. regex) then it's fine and that we shouldn't be closing them (downvote of course being up to the voter. Will look for source.

Comment: I have one OP asking me about how to use a handler, the class name of his problem code is "Adviseme" :D

Comment: Define “give me the code”. One person's “give me the code” question is another person's clear, concise problem statement.

Comment: @OGHaza show me. I remember him saying something quite different.

Comment: @JanDvorak You're right - on finding source, it's not that he thinks the questions should be allowed (and he's actually referring to those that lack "minial understanding" not gimme teh codez), he just thinks its more efficient to downvote them to oblivion [see last section here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210868/241771) <- thats the answer I was remembering but it's not all that relevant now that I have found it

Comment: @OGHaza I'm doing both - downvoting and closing.

Comment: @Gilles See edit. I asked one "give me the code" question, and hopefully I explained clearly.

Answer (score -2):

It is not about whether it asks for code or not. It's about the content of the post.

In order to be on a valid post, it needs to stay away from all these points :

> (Some questions are still off-topic, even if they don't fit into one of the categories listed below):
>
> Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.
>
> Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.
>
> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.
>
> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.
>
> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.
>
> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.
>
> Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools.

If it falls into one of those categories, even slightly, then it is no welcomed on the site.