# Allow quick categorization of downvotes / hint templates

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes

When a reviewer feels something is off about a question, he/she has two choices:

- Flagging the question with a category
- Downvote and optionally leave a comment

Leaving a comment is encouraged by a message saying something like: 'Please consider adding a comment ...'

However, writing a comment takes time (unless one has a user-script with templates), and I assume many downvotes have common causes, such as:

- Mostly off-topic (but not in the off-topic list of reasons in the flags)
- Badly formatted
- Badly phrased
- Answer easily found via search engine, did not read the manual

I think it would be helpful if there was a one-click way of justifying a downvote, possibly adding a auto-generated comment (or an upvote on the same comment category).

Alternatively providing comment templates in the UI, such as these already shared in questions like this (which indicates there is a whole cult about many new posts doing the same mistakes requiring same old comments):
*[Repository of useful pro-forma comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments)*

Comment: I agree. Looks similar enough to be considered duplicate.

Comment: There are existing user scripts that make this was.  The problem with this suggestion is the human element, people don’t like hearing there is a problem with their question, I have in the past been attacked for the comments that are already automatically submitted with regards the review process.  Until these suggestions can be made anonymous I don’t see how they will be helpful, in my experience, they will just cause people to attack those that submit these comments

Comment: @Rambound: I do not suggest for comments/hints to be mandatory, only for them to be one-click efforts. I start to think that stackexchange forums require user-scripts to be usable for answerers/reviewers.