# How can I get the table structure in answer

Tags: discussion, support

How to get the table structure which is present in the answer of the post?

[This self-left-join is returning more records than I expected it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654982/this-self-left-join-is-returning-more-records-than-i-expected-it-to/15655039)

Comment: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the facility of [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Just run query as `Plaintext Output`

[image]

**OR**

Try this website, Just put you plain text. it will give you exact same output you want

http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: +1 Thanks but I was looking for this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-to-format-sql-tables-in-a-stack-overflow-post

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli check my updated answer, i have added one link. this is usefull